# command pattern vs strategy pattern in Javascript

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, strategy-pattern, command-pattern

Strategy pattern and command patternz are very similar. I just want to confirm my understand of their differences.

Can I say with both design patterns, they both require to implement the methods in the interface. The difference is that with command pattern, with the constructor, you have to create the command class, like the below `AddThenMultiplyCommand`, however, with the strategy pattern, you don't need create the class in the constructor, and when you implement the interface method, you just call the function directly, like `AddThenMultiplyStrategy`, it calls the add method and multiple method directly without create them in the constructor.

Is my understand correct?

code link: https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-forked-c64qpw?file=/src/index.ts:0-1915

```
interface Action {
    execute(currentValue: number): number;
}

class AddCommand implements Action {
    private valueToAdd;

    constructor(valueToAdd: number) {
        this.valueToAdd = valueToAdd;
    }

    execute(currentValue: number) {
        return currentValue + this.valueToAdd;
    }
}

class MultiplyCommand implements Action {
    private valueToMultiply;

    constructor(valueToMultiply: number) {
        this.valueToMultiply = valueToMultiply;
    }

    execute(currentValue: number) {
        return currentValue * this.valueToMultiply;
    }
}

class AddThenMultiplyCommand implements Action {
    private addCommand: AddCommand;
    private multiplyCommand: MultiplyCommand;

    constructor(valueToAdd: number, valueToMultiply: number) {
        this.addCommand = new AddCommand(valueToAdd);
        this.multiplyCommand = new MultiplyCommand(valueToMultiply);
    }

    execute(currentValue: number) {
        const newValue = this.addCommand.execute(currentValue);
        return this.multiplyCommand.execute(newValue);
    }
}

class AddThenMultiplyStrategy implements Action {
    private valueToAdd;
    private valueToMultiply;

    constructor(valueToAdd: number, valueToMultiply: number) {
        this.valueToAdd = valueToAdd;
        this.valueToMultiply = valueToMultiply;
    }

    execute(currentValue: number) {
        // run add
        const add = new AddCommand(this.valueToAdd);
        // run multiple
        const multiple = new MultiplyCommand(this.valueToMultiply);
        const newValue = multiple.execute(add.execute(currentValue));
        return newValue;
    }
}

const add = new AddCommand(5);
console.log(add.execute(6)); // 5+6

const multiple = new MultiplyCommand(5);
console.log(multiple.execute(6)); // 5*6

const addThenMultiplyCommand = new AddThenMultiplyCommand(5, 6);
console.log(addThenMultiplyCommand.execute(5)); // (5+5)*6

const addThenMultiplyStrategy = new AddThenMultiplyStrategy(5, 6);
console.log(addThenMultiplyStrategy.execute(5)); // (5+5)*6
```

Answer (score 0):

The differences between command pattern and strategy pattern are:

- In the command pattern, in addition to command and invoker objects, there are receiver objects. If there is no receiver object like in your example, the code structure of the two patterns looks the same.
- The way to distinguish them is to consider: the goal of all strategy objects is always the same, they are just different ways to achieve that goal. But for command objects, their goals are not always the same.
- The command pattern also has undo and redo functions.
- The macro command can be implemented using command pattern and composite pattern.